# How to read messages off an IMAP server with libcurl and C:

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, curl, imap, libcurl

I am trying to retrieve messages from an IMAP server using libcurl.  Here is the code I am using from an online example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void){
   CURL *curl;
   CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;

   curl = curl_easy_init();
   if(curl) { 
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "user");
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "secret");
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.example.com/INBOX/;UID=1");
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
     res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
     if(res != CURLE_OK)
       fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
     curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
   }
return (int)res;
```

}

unfortunately this doesn't work.  I get the following output:

`C SELECT INBOX/;UID=1`
`< C NO Mailbox doesn't exist: INBOX.;UID=1`
`* Select failed`

if instead of `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.example.com/INBOX/;UID=1");` i put just `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.example.com/INBOX);` then i actually get useful output about the the INBOX, like i'm supposed to, with no errors.

I'm compiling with gcc on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

*Just for the people who reads this after all this time*

The code runs for me if I put Google Mail account. Like this:

```
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX/;UID=1");
```

(compiled in ubuntu using gcc)

Comment: the examples on the curl-site uses "imap://..." - yours has "imaps://" - saved my soul here, after even more time :) thx

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the trailing slash to your URL, i.e. use `imaps://imap.example.com/INBOX;UID=1`.

Comment: Still gives the same message: C NO Mailbox doesn't exist: INBOX;UID=1

Comment: How does a protocol trace look like?